# Combining view class with layout and {{#each}} multiple times gives incorrect behavior

Tags: ember.js

I'm seeing some very strange behavior in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SphtKr/uunGr/).

I am building an accordion control (hopefully eventually a good contribution to ember-bootstrap), and so I built a view class that uses `layout` to wrap the contents of the view:

```
Bootstrap.Accordion = Ember.View.extend({
    tagName: 'div',
    classNames: 'accordion',
    layout: Ember.Handlebars.compile('{{yield}}') 
});
```

Then I use it like so, with the `{{#view}}` helper, and include an `{{#each}}` block which will eventually include other views to set up the inside of the accordion control. And in one case so far, I do this twice in the same template, to display different information in two different accordion controls, sort of like this:

```
{{#view Bootstrap.Accordion}}
  {{#each content}}
    <div><strong>Field 1:</strong> {{field1}}</div>
  {{/each}}
{{/view}}

{{#view Bootstrap.Accordion}}
  {{#each content}}
    <div><strong>Field 2:</strong> {{field2}}</div>
  {{/each}}
{{/view}}
```

But, as you can see in the fiddle, this produces a very unexpected result. Basically, the second instance of the view is an exact copy of the first. Even the static content inside the `{{#each}}` block is not right:

```
Field 1: Instance 1 Field 1
Field 1: Instance 2 Field 1
Field 1: Instance 1 Field 1
Field 1: Instance 2 Field 1
```

However, if I put something between the `{{#view...}}` and `{{#each}}` helpers, it behaves as expected:

```
{{#view Bootstrap.Accordion}}
  Fourth try...
  {{#each content}}
    <div><strong>Field 4:</strong> {{field4}}</div>
  {{/each}}
{{/view}}
```

So, it *looks* like something about the similarity of the content directly within the `{{#view}}` helper causes the result to be cached by Handlebars...or something. That's just a wild hypothesis. Can anyone see what's going wrong here?

(Note that the Bootstrap library is not included in the fiddle, so it can't be that Bootstrap is goofing something up.)

Comment: True, I do mention [ember-bootstrap], but it's tangential to the question...just didn't want anyone to think the question itself pertains to ember-bootstrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a bug.

This [github issue](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/2210) was created today, only with the `{{#linkTo}}` helper.

Looks like this is occurring with all block helpers.